# Instrumented Android Unit Test and ProGuard

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I have an app and I am writing unit test case for it.
My test case gives huge list of warnings and 1 Error
Followed following link and child pages [Building Instrumented Unit Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)

**Error and Some Warnings**

> Warning:there were 10 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>            You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
>            If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
>            the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
>   Warning:there were 5 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
>            You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
>            be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
>   Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
>            Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
>            You may need to recompile the code.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
>   Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebugAndroidTest FAILED
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebugAndroidTest'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

**If I remove proguard from debug, I get 64K error!**

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

What am I doing wrong?

**app build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tyagiabhinav.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
dependencies 
{
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
   ......
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
}
```

**Test Java Class**

```
package com.tyagiabhinav.xyz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import com.tyagiabhinav.xyz.Util.PrefHelper;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

/**
 * Created by abhinavtyagi on 24/08/16.
 */


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class PrefTester {

    Context mMockContext;

    private PrefTester() {
        super();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mMockContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        PrefHelper.init(mMockContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSharedPref(){
        Assert.assertEquals(false,PrefHelper.isLoggedIn());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running proguard on your debug build.  Proguard can remove classes from the java code.  Turn off proguard by setting "minifyEnabled false" in the build.gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Comment: If I remove proguard, I receive 64k error. My code is not big one. It's a small application. But somehow after writing this test case I am seeing 64k error while compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes and issue got resolved!

**Test Code**
Changed the way of getting context by opening a splash screen

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class PrefTester {

    Context mMockContext;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SplashActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(SplashActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mMockContext = mActivityRule.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        PrefHelper.init(mMockContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSharedPref(){
        Assert.assertEquals(false,PrefHelper.isLoggedIn());
    }

}
```

**build.gradle(app)**
set proguard false in debug -> `minifyEnabled false`
enabled multidex -> `multiDexEnabled true` 
added dependency -> `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

I had tested the build.gradle approach prior to posting this question, I think I was fetching the context the wrong way. The combination of above changes have worked for me now.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in your proguard-rules.pro file? You could try removing that and simply using the default android rules.

As a note, I think you may want to re-evaluate your dependencies. From the snippet of your gradle file you showed, it seems unlikely that you'd be hitting the 64K dex limit with just those dependencies. Are you including more libraries that you didn't list above? Are there libraries in jar files in your project? (That could easily explain the number of methods)

Multidex is kind of a hack - you really shouldn't use it unless you have no choice. There are performance implications/etc to using it at all, and some strange gotchas that can pop up unexpectedly around which classes live in which dex file. For instance - any class referenced from the manifest must end up in your primary dex file, which can put weird constraints on you.

Comment: It's solved... Cleaned the code several times and then rebuild it.

Comment: Definitely glad it's fixed! :-) But my reasoning for answering here was to point out that multidex doesn't seem to be the appropriate way to fix this problem from the information you provided.